# No provider for Http! - Angular 4 + Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, typescript

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.angularonrails.com/getting-started-with-angular-and-rails/#comment-40996), and am having trouble getting it going.

I am using Angular 4.2.4.

```
[Error] ERROR
Error: No provider for Http!
injectionError — core.es5.js:1169
...
  View_AppComponent_Host_0 (AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:4)
  ...
```

As I understand it, a few things have changed with Angular since this tutorial was written, including the replacement of this:

```ts
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

with this:

```ts
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

I have tried this and added `HttpModule` to the `imports` array in `app.module.ts.

`app.component.ts`

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  books;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    http.get('http://localhost:3000/books.json')
      .subscribe(res => this.books = res.json());
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your `app.module.ts` and your `AppComponent`, and it's really not advisable following tutorials from before the `RC.5` version, this is when they introduced `NgModule`

Comment: @PierreDuc Added to question.

Comment: In `app.module.ts` import and add `HttpModule`  to imports array., like : `imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule,AppModule ]`

Answer (score 3):

You should import the `Http` provider from `@angular/http` inside your `AppComponent`, and add the `HttpModule` to the imports array of your `AppModule`:

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  books;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    http.get('http://localhost:3000/books.json')
      .subscribe(res => this.books = res.json());
  }
}
```

**AppModule**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppModule,
    HttpModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```